# summing up key value pairs in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am iterating through a dict and counting up the number of items that are of a certain format in the dict.

```
sum(1 for key in mydict.keys() if re.match('^D\\d{2}$',key))
```

I am trying to change it so that I can add up the combined sum of the values who’s keys match my regex format.
So instead of `‘1’` being added for each key that matches my format I want to the value of each matching key.

I was trying something like below but I get an error saying:  `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict_values'`

```
sum(mydict.values() for key in mydict.keys() if re.match('^D\\d{2}$',key))
```

Comment: Please add input data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the keys and values via `items` and you can sum the values:

```
sum(v for k, v in mydict.items() if re.match('^D\\d{2}$', k))
```

Note that I'm assuming the values in `mydict` are numeric -- if not, you'll want to sum `int(v)` (or maybe `float(v)`) instead of just `v`.